# How to write the bold * star?

Tags: support, markdown

The longer I am here, I've gotten used to formatting rules here.

But one thing is still unclear for me. You can write a **bold** text by surrounding it with `**` two stars at both sides. Like `**I am fat**`.

How to make the star `*` character bold itself? I approach to something like this `*****` that's getting on my nerve.

I assume it'd be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, [special characters in Markdown can be escaped by prefixing them with a backslash](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) (`\`).

So, if you do `**\***`, you will get a bold asterisk: *****
<sub>(but it's pretty hard to tell the difference between bold and regular with this single character)</sub>

If you want a *real* star, you can use the Unicode character `&#x2605;`: ★

(Simply typing `*****`, as suggested in the question, won't work. You'll get a horizontal line instead.)

Comment: Twinkle, twinkle, little _real_ star. The difference between the bold and non-bold asterisk is practically negligible; I definitely wouldn't notice any intended effect that bold was supposed to bring.

Answer (score 2):

### Markdown:

```
**\***
```

> *****

### Html:

```
<b>*</b>
```

> *****

Most markdown special characters can be escaped by the `\`.

The difference between bold and non-bold `*` is pretty subtle though.